# Change <C-j> binding for vim-latex

Tags: vim

I am using the C-j map for regular navigation in Vim; it is defined like this in .vimrc:

```
map <C-j> <C-e>
```

However, C-j is redfined in the latex suite. When I try to use the described (imaps.vim) way by doing:

```
imap <C-somekey> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
```

in .vimrc C-j still doesn't get mapped as it does without vim-latex installed.

The vim latex suite is installed in /usr/share/vimfiles/plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

err..right, this works:

```
" redef C-j to C-g
imap <C-g> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
nmap <C-g> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
```